# Get all fields of Bittorrent DHT messages using libtorrent

Tags: bittorrent, libtorrent

I'm interested in writing some code to visualize/analyze the BitTorrent mainline DHT using libtorrent.

My plan is to use the alerts api and subscribe to all `dht_notification`s. However, some notifications don't include all fields of the KRPC message (ex `dht_get_peers_alert` doesn't include IP address).

Should I modify the alerts framework, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get full access to all DHT traffic is to subscribe to the `dht_log_category` of alerts and look for [dht_pkt_alert](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Alerts.html#dht-pkt-alert) which will contain a verbatim copy of the whole DHT message, for any incoming and outgoing packets.